# How do you find an AirTag on the web

Tags: icloud, find-my-iphone, airtag

How do you find an AirTag on the web using iCloud.com's FindMyiPhone (not the app?)

Comment: [iCloud 'Find My' page](https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my/) shows AirTag so it MAY now be possible. Although [iCloud User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/locate-a-device-mmfc0f2442/icloud) doesn't mention AirTag, but maybe they simply haven't updated it. AirTag uses bluetooth so it can't directly tell iCloud, however every iOS device checks for AirTags near it & relay its location (GPS coordinates from helper phones likely) to iCloud. Apple calls this the 'Find My network' as detailed on [its main page](https://www.apple.com/airtag/)

Comment: I'll be testing the possibility in near future & will try to remember to post an answer if I find its possible

Comment: Confirmed icloud.com/find will not show AirTags after I setup a COUPLE new ones :(
[Here is a related article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211331) that infers these things only work with the app...hopefully for now

Answer (score 12):

AirTags can only be tracked with Find My app, either on an iPhone/iPad or Mac - but not on the web.

Instructions from Apple for locating and AirTag:

> Open the Find My app, then tap the Items tab.
>
> Choose the AirTag you want to locate in the Items list.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210967

Comment: Has this changed? Will they be adding it to iCloud eventually?

Comment: @Aaron_H There have been no announcements/changes on the matter

Comment: It's true, but it's sooo annoying. Why is this not available in the browser?! Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 2):

You can't find it on the web using https://www.icloud.com/find.

It is only visible in the owner's iPhone via the [Find My app](https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my/). It works away from the owner's phone.

Basically, it updates its location every time the tag finds any iPhone around.

Answer (score -8):

It doesn't have a built-in GPS signal sender, so it can only be used by your cell-phone App which means the range is under 15 meters.

Comment: But you can find AirTags that are more than 15 metres away - so how does it do that? AiurTag uses any devices on the Find My network not just your iPhone

Comment: Also AirTags don't have GPS in them.  No way they could last for a year with a coin battery if they did.  You can find the location when you're far away because every Apple Device that receives them will report their location when they see one.