# Is there a way to find AirTags programmatically?

Tags: icloud, airtag

I want to search for my AirTags from the **web**, **macOS**, **Android**, and/or **my server**. There does not appear to be an API available to do this. Does a method exist to read this info or automatically send this info from my iPhone?

Comment: Officially the FindMy API is not public. But you can have a look at [this](https://github.com/MauriceConrad/iCloud-API#find-me)

Comment: this work only to find iphone and mac but not airtags @PtitXav

Answer (score 1):

AirTags are not shown in the web app - only devices and friends so you’re out of luck “officially”.

- https://www.icloud.com/find/

The SDK / API is private to Apple, so unless someone reverse engineers it and fakes out the encryption and traffic, you won't get additional access to the location data and will need to use the apps Apple delivered for getting this location data.

In May 2022 - only the native app (iOS / iPadOS / macOS) shows AirTag.

> Precision Finding is compatible with iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone 11 Pro Max, iPhone 12, iPhone 12 mini, iPhone 12 Pro, iPhone 12 Pro Max, iPhone 13, iPhone 13 mini, iPhone 13 Pro, and iPhone 13 Pro Max.

https://www.apple.com/airtag/

Comment: Airtags cannot be found through the web interface, only via the find my app on apple devices.

Comment: How is my edit @anonymous ?

Comment: The precision finding is separate from being able to find the airtag, as precision finding needs an iphone 11 or later with u1 chip. A better source to credit is https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/420125/406217

Comment: i can read info in the app official ? and after send to server. exist any method to scraping the app ( in my phone )

Comment: Depends how clever you are at processing screen shots I suppose @alejandropereiraALEW140 you get to see the address in the USA, relative time ago it was located (e.g. 6 minutes ago) and there are actions to get directions to the address which launch that automation in maps. All accessibility is in play, voiceover, spoken content, https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/get-started-with-accessibility-features-iph3e2e4367/ios but no API or data dump to a file.